# Issue with x-axis ticks in dc.js

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using `d3 v5.9.2`, `dc v3.0.12` to render a line chart but the ticks in x-axis seems to be having some issue. The data supplied has to be plotted with date along x Axis and value along y-axis since it's a timeline graph.

```
const line = lineChart(divRef);
const crossfilterDimension = dx.dimension(dimension);
const firstRecord = crossfilterDimension.bottom(1)[0];
const lastRecord = crossfilterDimension.top(1)[0];
line
  .dimension(crossfilterDimension)
  .x(
    scaleTime().domain([
      firstRecord[Object.keys(firstRecord)[0]],
      lastRecord[Object.keys(lastRecord)[0]]
    ])
  )
  .xUnits(timeYear)
  .xAxisLabel(xAxis.label)
  .yAxisLabel(yAxis.label)
  .renderDataPoints({ radius: 2, fillOpacity: 0.8, strokeOpacity: 0.0 })
  .group(
    count
      ? crossfilterDimension.group().reduceCount()
      : crossfilterDimension.group().reduceSum(group)
  );
line
  .yAxis()
  .ticks(yAxis.ticks)
  .tickFormat(yAxis.tickFormat);
return line;
```

[image: Timeline graph]

Comment: It would help if you said what the problem is, especially since you haven't shown a reproducible example, a sample of your data set, or complete code. "Seems to be having some problem" is more polite than "it doesn't work" but not any more descriptive.

Comment: @gordon sorry I forgot to post the sample data. Well the problem is if you see the X axis in the image attached you can see that ticks are messed up.

Comment: I'm not sure what the intention is behind `.ticks(yAxis.ticks)` since you don't show the declaration of `yAxis.ticks` but if that is a number you could be telling [axis.ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/v1.0.12/README.md#axis_ticks) to display too many ticks? Or you could [rotate them](http://www.d3noob.org/2016/08/rotating-text-labels-for-graph-axis-in.html), I guess. Again, "messed up" isn't very descriptive. It helps if you say what you want.

Comment: Yes sorry. I messed up. Will modify my question to make it a generic example. Yes it's a number. But I have applied ticks only to y axis and not X axis yet X axis ticks have an issue. And also applying ticks just means it's a suggestion and not a fixed requirement right?

Comment: Right, it's a suggestion. How are the ticks messed up? Are you talking about how they are too crowded or something else?

Comment: Yes about them being so crowded. It's like no one could figure out what's what in that axis.

Comment: So you could rotate them (link above) or ask d3.axis to show less of them. I think it's too hard a problem for d3.axis to be completely automatic, you usually have to customize them somehow.